How to find the modid of a LogEvent or LogRecord in minecraft modding?
I want to find if a LogRecord or LogEvent  is from a a particular mod using its modid. i have a HashSet<String> holding desired modids.
I have no clue how to do this. With a LogRecord / LogEvent and minecraft forge api in log4j, how to get the modid a log message is sent from?
